# How to find the current staging directory in spark submit for cluster mode?

Tags: java, apache-spark, hdfs, spark-streaming, hadoop-yarn

I'm passing the local files in spark submit using --files and I now want to download the files from the staging directory to local worker nodes.
But how do I get the path for the staging directory in java code.

Answer (score 1):

Files passed with `--files` are automatically uploaded to all worker nodes. You can access them in your code via 
[SparkFiles.get()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkFiles.html)

You can get the directory on Spark worker where these files are stored via [SparkFiles.getRootDirectory()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkFiles.html#getRootDirectory())

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/41678839/7417402