# Apache Spark submit --files java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a spark script that reads the content of a file `spark.read.textFile(filePath)`
I run it from the container of the master itself and try to pass this file with the `--files` param such as

```
./spark-submit --class nameOfClass --files local/path/to/file.csv --master spark://master_ip generated_executable.jar local/path/to/file.csv`
```

But then I get the error

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/local/path/to/file.csv does not exist
```

I tried changing the line to:
`spark.read.textFile(SparkFiles.get(fileName))`

but the error persists, now it says

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/mnt/mesos/sandbox/spark-946bbaef-a258-4951-9b15-bec77b78bf5d/userFiles-3f9dcf85-4114-4968-b625-6bb1498f568d/file.csv does not exist
```

If I manually add the file to each worker, it works. But I don't want to do that. Is there a way to pass the file from the context where it is submitting the job?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get path to the uploaded file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41677897/how-to-get-path-to-the-uploaded-file)

Comment: No, it does not. I'll update the question with that info

Answer (score 0):

one good alternative would be to put the csv file to hdfs. then you don't have to take care of the file residing on every executor. I don't think it's a common pattern to pass a file to a spark-submit invocation in order to read it.

assuming it's located at `hdfs://tmp/file.csv` you can read it by coding

> spark.read.textFile("/tmp/file.csv")

which leads to the opportunity to dispense passing the file via `--files` fully

---

but what you could do is running the job in local mode. this is a easy workaround avoiding to place the file on every node manually. then spark should find the file just as you want under

> file:/local/path/to/file.csv

i hope that helps