# Accessing file as an argument to PySpark driver - Google Dataproc Jobs

Tags: python, apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc

As a part of `PySpark` Job on `gcloud dataproc` we have multiple files , one of them is a `json` which is passed to the driver python file. The driver file itself sits on a google storage(gs file system).

We are trying to submit this job using the [gcloud dataproc api](https://googleapis.dev/python/dataproc/latest/index.html) for python.

The configuration used for the job object in [submit_job](https://googleapis.dev/python/dataproc/latest/gapic/v1beta2/api.html#google.cloud.dataproc_v1beta2.JobControllerClient.submit_job) is :

```
job_details = {
        'placement': {
            'cluster_name': cluster_name
        },
        'pyspark_job': {
            'main_python_file_uri': 'gs://driver_file.py',
            'python_file_uris':['gs://package.whl'],
            'file_uris':['gs://config.json'],
            'args':['gs://config.json']
        }
    }
```

My understanding from this is `config.json` should be made available to the driver , which gcloud properly does from the logs - `Downloading gs://config.json to /tmp/tmprandomnumber/fop_gcp_1.json`

From the `file_uris` of [gcloud documentation page](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.dataproc.v1beta2#google.cloud.dataproc.v1beta2.PySparkJob)  this seems correct-

> HCFS URIs of files to be copied to the working directory of Python
>   drivers and distributed tasks. Useful for naively parallel tasks.

Now after a lot of debugging we stumbled upon `SparkFiles.get('config.json')` which is meant to get the files which were uploaded to the driver based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41677897/how-to-get-path-to-the-uploaded-file)

But this also fails with `[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/hadoop/spark/tmp/spark-random-number/userFiles-random-number/config.json'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright figured it, out posting it so that it can help someone out there!

Use the [`SparkContext.addFile`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkContext) -

> Add a file to be downloaded with this Spark job on every node.

```
SparkContext.addFile(config_file_name)
```

And then a simple

```
from pyspark import SparkFiles
SparkFiles.get(config_file_name)
```

**Note: All this can only be done after the SparkContext is initialised in your code.**