# How to get staging directory in running Spark?

Tags: apache-spark

My question is exactly same as this [How to get path to the uploaded file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41677897/how-to-get-path-to-the-uploaded-file)

But when I try it, I get different results.

I can see my file uploaded into staging directory in log as

`20/05/04 15:30:17 INFO Client: Uploading resource file:/home1/irteam/fileName.txt -> hdfs://aaa.aaa.aaa:8020/user/irteam/.sparkStaging/application_1554781627650_743169/fileName.txt`

But when I try get it with

`spark.read.text(SparkFiles.get('fileName.txt'))`

I get error as

`Input path does not exist: hdfs://aaa.aaa.aaa:8020/tmp/spark-d5854059-2389-4623-a5ce-431789d81bd3/ ...`

That is not the staging directory. How can I get it?

Thank you for reading my question.

Answer (score 0):

Once the file is uploaded to the tmp directory.
Spark can access it like it is on local env so in order to read the file you can simply try:

```
spark.read.text('filename.txt')
#incase of csv file
spark.read.csv('filename.csv')
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry, I should have told, that my spark is running on cluster. In local, that would be great.

Comment: Then you can directly read the file spark.read.text('/home1/irteam/fileName.txt') by providing your complete local file path

Comment: I add it as --files /home1/irteam/fileName.txt, then I call it spark.read.text('/home1/irteam/fileName.txt'), but java.io.FileNotFoundException. file:/home1/irteam/fileName.txt does not exist.